# UltraEdit never open in hex?

Tags: ultraedit

Is there a way to disable hex mode? So that especially .txt files are always opened in ASCII (normal) view.

I already tried: {Menu Advanced, Configuration, File Handling, Unicode/UTF-8 Detection, Disable automatic detection of hex file format on reload} = yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create following macro:
(Macro –> Edit Macro -> New Macro)

```
IfExtIs "txt"
InsertMode
ColumnModeOff
HexOff
EndIf
```

Where “txt” – file extension.
Then save it and add to Macro -> Set auto load (Number of times to execute: 1,, and specify correct macro name and file that contains this macro)

Comment: Thanks, i programmed this like you said ... if all files open in txt from now on, i'll know it worked!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [UltraEdit forums](http://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3019), it's not possible. The suggested solution to use a macro did not work for me.